# Run https://github.com/akella/webgl-mouseover-effects code locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I want to implement image hover effect like on this website https://miew.pt/, and the closest example I got or came across can be found here https://github.com/akella/webgl-mouseover-effects

1. I have downloaded and extracted the files but when I run/open e.g step3.html, I am getting errors.
2. I have run yarn add  but still getting same error as in point 1.

The error in point 1 & 2 is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

What's the correct way to set up the code locally(Win 10)?

Answer (score 0):

I just used:

```
npm install
npm run parcel -- step3.html
```

and it worked on my setup (Win 10 + NPM 6.14.14 + Node v14.17.5)

Can you try again with this setup ?

[image]